# Lucene - Specialized TokenStream/Analyzer given a set of indexable keywords

Tags: lucene

I have the following situation
I have a collection of documents to index. But I need to be selective in what I index.

**Selection criteria**: the document must contain one of the keywords from a given `Set`.

That part is easy, I can check if any of those keywords are present in the document and only then index the document.
The tricky situation is (for me anyway!), that I want to index only these keywords. And these keywords can be multiworded, or regex expressions as well, say.

What these keywords are going to be is meaningless to this post, because I can abstract that out - I can generate the list of keywords that need to be indexed.

Is there an existing TokenStream, Analyzer, Filter combination that I can use?
And if there isn't, please could someone point me in the right direction.

---

If my question isn't clear enough:

```
HashSet<String> impKeywords = new HashSet<String>(new String[] {"Java", "Lucene"});
```

I have a class `Content` which I use, say:

```
Content content = new Content("I am only interested in Java, Lucene, Nutch, Luke, CommonLisp.");
```

And, say I have a method to get matching keywords:

```
HashSet<String> matchingKeywords = content.getMatchingKeywords(impKeywords); // returns a set with "Java" and "Lucene"
```

And if there are matchingKeywords, only then proceed to index the document; so:

```
if(!matchingKeywords.isEmpty()) {
    // prepare document for indexing, and index.
    // But what should be my Analyzer and TokenStream?
}
```

I want to be able to create an Analyzer with a TokenStream that only returns these matching keywords, so only these tokens are indexed.

**End notes**: One possibility appears to be that for each document I add a variable number of fields with each of the matching keywords. Where these fields are Indexed but not Analyzed using `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED`. However, it would be better if I'm able to figure out a pre-existing Analyzer/TokenStream for this purpose instead of playing around with fields.

Comment: Couldn't you just index the returned values from your call to `getMatchingKeywords`?  If you only want to index extracted keywords that you have already acquired, it doesn't make sense to pass the entirely of the `content` into an Analyzer.  Either index them as `NOT_ANALYZED`, or analyzed as keywords.  You should have no problems indexing them in the same field (that is, with the same field name when added to the `Document`).

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon So if I understand correctly, you are suggesting something like 
`for(String keyword: matchingKeywords)` 
`doc.add(new Field("keyword", keyword, Field.Store.No, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);` 
right?

And then my query should be a `BooleanQuery` of `PhrasalQuery`'s?

Comment: Since you are indexing without Analysis, and thus without tokenization, you should combine `TermQuery`s instead of `PhraseQuery`s.  Each keyword will be a single Term, even if they have multiple words.  Otherwise though, yes, that would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @femtoRgon's advise I have resolved the said problem as follows.

As explained in the question, I have:

```
HashSet<String> impKeywords = new HashSet<String>(new String[] {"Java", "Lucene"});
```

And I have a class `Content` which I use, say as follows:

```
Content content = new Content("I am only interested in Java, Lucene, Nutch, Luke, CommonLisp.");
```

And, I have a method to get matching keywords:

```
HashSet<String> matchingKeywords = content.getMatchingKeywords(impKeywords); // returns a set with "Java" and "Lucene" for this example `content`.
```

And if there are matchingKeywords, only then proceed to index the document; so while indexing I did:

```
if(!matchingKeywords.isEmpty()) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    for(String keyword: matchingKeywords) {   
        doc.add(new Field("keyword", keyword, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    }
    iwriter.addDocument(doc); // iwriter is the instance of IndexWriter
}
```

Then, while searching I created the following boolean query:

```
BooleanQuery boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();

for(String queryKeyword: searchKeywords)) {
    boolQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("keyword", queryKeyword)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}

ScoreDoc[] hits = isearcher.search(boolQuery, null, 1000).scoreDocs; // isearcher is the instance of IndexSearcher
```

Hope this answer helps someone with similar needs.